# Can't change background-image of a div

Tags: javascript, css, background-image

I'm trying to change background-image of a div #image by hovering on thumbnail images (something like a simple slider)
My plunker is provided below.

1- First I tried to do like: element.style.backgroundImage
but i got this in the console: 
[image: Using .style.backgroundImage]

2- Then i tried something like element.backgroundImage
although it looks good in the console but didnt work, here is the console:
[image: Without .style]

Note: I don't want to use any library, just want to study JavaScript core.

```
      my plunker
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/Mk0HSTYvQ4isVKjM7IEt?p=preview

## update:

1- I noticed that i was doing wrong interpolation here:

```
var bgI_value = 'url('+ src + ');';
```

it should be:

```
var bgI_value = 'url("'+ src + '");';
```

2- The suggestion from Alexandru to remove the simicolon was a good point.

3- the suggestion from Sharma to add .style.backgroundImage was a good point too.

so my code was missing these three corrections!

Thanks all.

Comment: Please post the text and not the image. It is not readable. The link to the plunker is not working either.

Comment: That is not a Plunker.

Comment: why not use css :hover?

Comment: Why the down votes? you guys could have notified me with my wrong plunker and that was enough.

Comment: Someone else is downvoting everyone on the page, can`t understand why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in the way you are changing the background image:

```
image.backgroundImage= bgI_value;
```

What it should be is:

```
image.style.backgroundImage= bgI_value;
```

Note that this here is correct:

```
var bgI_value = 'url('+ src + ')';
```

Here is the Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/NX1cgmzudJjFbM80q3eI?p=preview

Comment: I just explained in the question above that i have tried that too but it doesnt work, it is actually gives empty string ,, see the pics above please

Comment: someone is down voting everyone here

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution:

Please change

```
var bgI_value = 'url('+ src + ');';
```

TO

```
var bgI_value = 'url('+ src + ')';
```

Comment: I just did that (removing the simicolon) and updating the plunker so u can have a look, but still not working.

Comment: for me it is work perfectly ! you must keep first version of plunker

Comment: Correction. I had your conventions mixed up. Apologies

Comment: @A.Sharma, my solution it works perfectly for first version posted by shireef khatab

Comment: @AlexandruMihai Please test your solution with the OP's original Plunker without changing `image.backgroundImage` to `image.style.backgroundImage`

Comment: Thank you very much, ur help is appreciated but i it was three little pieces missing and it just worked after Sharma`s answer, but i really appreciate your effort, Thump up

Comment: @A.Sharma, you're right.I said that when I answered to question ,the plunker does not contained the mistake you explained.